# How to disable Field Accessor Dialog in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

After updating Android Studio 4.2.1 when I want to see the usage of variables (ctrl+click) a dialog is being shown with two options, Include accessors and Exclude accessors, How to disable Field Accessor Dialog in android studio?

[image]

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do that as of now (at least through the IDE settings).